# Compute elementary symmetric functions via MATLAB

Tags: combinatorics, matlab, symmetric-polynomials

For any given numbers $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$, the k-th elementary symmetric function is
$$
E_k=\sum_{1\le i_1<...<i_k\le n} x_{i_1}x_{i_2}...x_{i_k},~~~~~~~k=1,...,n.
$$

Given a specified n-tuple of numbers, how do you compute $E_k$ via Matlab?

I wrote the following code. I am not sure whether this can be improved (from computational cost/time point of view).

```
x=rand(1,n) % randomly generate a vector of n entries 

syms t;

p=expand(prod(t+x)); % p is a monic polynomial

c=sym2poly(p); % coefficient vector
```

One finds that $E_k=c(k+1)$, $k=1, \ldots, n$.

Thank you.

Comment: the smart way to do this, working with floating point arithmetic, is to consider them as roots of a monic polynomial $p(u)=(u-x_1)(u-x_2)...(u-x_n)= E_0\cdot u^n - E_1\cdot u^{n-1} + .... + (-1)^{n-1}\cdot  E_{n-1}\cdot u + (-1)^n\cdot E_n$  and use the FFT to interpolate/recover the result.

Comment: @user8675309 not "roots" but "coefficients". Besides, I don't understand what the FFT would do...

Comment: @JeanMarie check: $p(x_1) = 0$ therefore $x_1$ is a root of $p$.  Ditto for $x_2$ and so on... **edit:** Oh I see. my commentI used the vague 'them' in reference to the $x_i$ not to the $E_i$ hence the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative.

Do you know that the "nchoosek" function used for having plain binomial coefficients  nchoosek(n,k)$ \ = \ \binom{n}{k}$ possesses an extension where the first parameter instead of being a number $n$ is a set with $n$ elements giving the following alternative to your program using only numerical functions (see explanation below):

> ```
> n=4;
> x=rand(1,n);
> for k=1:n
>    T(k)=sum(prod(nchoosek(x,k),2));
> end;
> T
> ```

Explanation on an example:

nchoosek([a b c],k) gives the different sets with $k=2$ elements chosen among the set $\{a,b,c\}$ under the form :

$$\begin{matrix}a&b\\a&c\\b&c\end{matrix}$$

Therefore, in order to get the elementary symmetric polynomial: $ab+ac+bc$, the program upwards

- in a first step (function "prod"), produces products $ab, \ \ ac, \ \ bc$ of entries line by line because we have indicated that we want the product done this way : this is why the second parameter $2$ has been added. Otherwise, "prod(x)" would have produced $a^2b \ \ \ bc^2$ which is not what we want... Explanation: by default, with Matlab, the application of an operator (such as multiplication, max, etc.) to a 2 dimensional array is vertical.
- in a second step (function "sum"), one sums $ab, \ \ ac, \ \ bc$ to obtain $ab+ac+bc$. This time, no added parameter because we work vertically...

Comment: I have compared the execution time: it is in favor of your method ; on my (quite slow) PC, till $n=12$ both methods have short ($\approx 10$ ms) execution time but when $n>15$ my method takes some seconds, whereas yours remains with almost the same time...

Comment: Thank you very much on this. I guessed that using definition directly would take longer execution time.

Comment: I thought to vote up, but my reputation is less than 15, so I instead to vote accept.